# Quartz .net - Abort/Stop Current Execution of Job & Pause All the triggers

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

In My Project I am using Quartz.net Scheduler (3.0.7), Now There are some automated verification process which reads the DB and process it and generate output based on few conditions, (You can take example of Email Sending Mechanism which sends email read from DB and Send to Respective mail address) Now If we assume There are 300 Request to be processed and each will take long time to complete, Now There is one feature required which pause the current execution of the job, what i want is that if from 300 requests 25 is completed and currently 26 is running so the job should complete the 26th execution but should stop rest of the request.

What I have tried is to implement the Pause and Interrupt methods of Quartz.net

i.e. await scheduler.PauseJob(jobKey); &

await scheduler.Interrupt(jobKey);

Which Can Pause the upcoming executions, If I can get any Event or Token into Job Execution Class, I can achieve what i want.

IInterruptableJob Has been removed from the Quartz.net

If anyone can help me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [migration guide](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/migration-guide.html):

> `IInterruptableJob` interface has been removed. You need to check for `IJobExecutionContext`’s `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` to determine whether job interruption has been requested.

So combining the pause and observing the token should work.